# How to find rows with maximum in a group in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe like that:

| index | dmc1 | par | dummy | occur |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | d1 | p1 | a | 1 |
| 1 | d1 | p2 | b | 1 |
| 2 | d1 | p3 | c | 1 |
| 3 | d1 | p3 | d | 2 |
| 4 | d2 | p1 | e | 1 |
| 5 | d2 | p2 | f | 1 |
| 6 | d2 | p2 | g | 2 |
| 7 | d2 | p3 | h | 1 |

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dmc1': ['d1', 'd1', 'd1', 'd1','d2', 'd2', 'd2', 'd2'],
            'par': ['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p3', 'p1', 'p2', 'p2', 'p3'],
            'dummy': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'],
            'occur': ['1', '1', '1', '2', '1', '1', '2', '1']})
```

I want to group this table by "dmc1" and "par" and find in each group the member with the highest value of "occur" and keep only those rows. So I expect the result like this:

| index | dmc1 | par | dummy | occur |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | d1 | p1 | a | 1 |
| 0 | d1 | p2 | b | 1 |
| 0 | d1 | p3 | d | 2 |
| 0 | d2 | p1 | e | 1 |
| 0 | d2 | p2 | g | 2 |
| 0 | d2 | p3 | h | 1 |

I'm using python 3.6.10

I found this solution many times:

idx =  df.groupby(['dmc1','par'])['occur'].idxmax()

df_short = data.loc[idx]

but in my case it raises an error:
AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'idmax'

I also found the hint to use "idxmax()" instead of "idmax()" but this raises also an error:
raise ValueError

Would be grate to have a solution that is running in python 3.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need convert values to numeric first:

```
df['occur'] = df['occur'].astype(int)
df_short = data.loc[df.groupby(['dmc1','par'])['occur'].idxmax()]
```

Comment: Oh man, yes, you are right. Sometimes I can't see the wood for the trees.